# How to update other table's fields using Post request in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and I am having issues updating the other table's fields when Posting or creating new entry. I am not sure how to. And I have been figuring this out for 2 days on how to do this through serializer or better implement it if it's not through serializer.

Basically, I want to update the Fruits' status every time I create a delivery. So I can say if it's available or not. Below are the code snippet.

This is my model:

```html
class Delivery(models.Model):
    delivery_type = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.delivery_type

class Fruits(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    delivery = models.ManyToManyField(Delivery, related_name='fruits')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my serializer:

```html
class FruitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Fruits
        fields = "__all__"

class DeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fruits = FruitSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        delivery = Delivery.objects.create(
            delivery_type = validated_data['delivery_type'],
            driver_name = validated_data['driver_name']
            )
            
        #update the status field in Fruits Table
        fruits = validated_data.get('fruits')
        for fruit in fruits:
            fruit_data = Fruits(
                id = fruit['id'],
                status = "Not Available",
                delivery=delivery
            )
            fruit_data.save()
        return delivery
```

This is my view:

```html
class DeliverySerializerView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = DeliverySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud update many to many relation, in your case you just create separate Delivery and many Fruits objects.

After
`fruit_data.save()` try `delivery.fruits.add(fruit_data)`. 
[See this post for more info about many_to_many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

If you want update status for related fruits, you can do something like this
`delivery.fruits.all().update(status="foo")`